# Why does reloadRowsAtIndexPaths doesn't reload a cell's UILabel alpha value, but reloadData does?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

When I select a row, this method gets called:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [_historyEntryTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

And from my cellForRowAtIndexPath, I'm dynamically setting an alpha value for a UILabel.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *Cell = @"StandardCell";

    TWHistoryViewStandardCell *cell =
    (TWHistoryViewStandardCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cell];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (TWHistoryViewStandardCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HistoryViewStandardCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //...

    if (currentPick == PickDateFrom) {
        cell.hoursLabel.alpha = 1.0;
    } else {
        cell.hoursLabel.alpha = 0.7;
    }

    //...

}
```

If from my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method i call reloadData on my table view, the table shows the updated cells, with the expected alpha value. But reloadRowsAtIndexPath as no effect whatsoever.

Any reason why this might be happening?

**EDIT:**

"Hammer Fixed" by calling reloadData after reloadRowsAtIndexPath:

```
[_historyEntryTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[_historyEntryTableView reloadData];
```

It's not realy the answer for the question, but it will do for now.

Does someone know if there's something in the cell that must be called to re-render the alpha value? It's just the alpha value of the UILabel, because the text does change correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: Use breakpoints to see if cell.hoursLabel.alpha = 0.7; is called.

Comment: Try `[_historyEntryTableView beginUpdates]; [_historyEntryTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; [_historyEntryTableView endUpdates];`

Comment: Tried that already, no success. The cell does update if I scroll them out of view and then back in.